# Storing JS object inside value attribute in a radiobutton?

Tags: html, knockout.js

Is it valid HTML/HTML5 to store a JS object (not stringified) inside the value attribute of a radiobutton?

For an example, I'm using Knockout JS to set the value of a radiobutton to a JS object as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- ko foreach: $data.vehicles-->
<input type="radio" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.selVehicle" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Javascript:**

```
function ViewModel() {
  this.selVehicle = ko.observable();

  this.vehicles = ko.observableArray([new Vehicle('Toyota'), new Vehicle('Honda')]);
}

function Vehicle(name) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

When you run this, the value of the radiobutton will be "[Object object]" if you examine it with the console.

Answer (score 0):

its not about whether it is valid Html/Html5 attribute value, when using Knockout it is normal to use object in you data bindings. So in your radio button value is bind to Vehicle function, if you want to get name of your vehicle use `selVehicle().name()`, see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) in `foreach` binding.

**HTML**

```
<!-- ko foreach: vehicles-->
<input type="radio" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.selectedVehicle" />
<!-- /ko -->
<p data-bind="text: selectedVehicle().name">

</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function ViewModel() {
  this.selectedVehicle = ko.observable();

  this.vehicles = ko.observableArray([new Vehicle('Toyota'), new Vehicle('Honda')]);
}

function Vehicle(name) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/jmvtrinidad/sebpop9n/) the jsfiddle to try it out.